# Sharing a photo on Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to share a photo on Facebook. So I read this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/publish-to-feed/).

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
postParams.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");
```

In the last parameter, there is a link for uploading the picture but in my case I have to choose the picture from my SD Card and share on Facebook.

So, how can I do this thing? Am I going the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Request.newUploadPhotoRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/Request#newUploadPhotoRequest%28Session,%20Bitmap,%20Callback%29) to upload an image to Facebook.

Alternatively, you can create an [open graph story](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/), and attach photos to your open graph actions or objects.